Perlのモジュール、File::BOMとencodingの順番について
Perlでopen関数の第２引数で
open my $fh, ">:via(File::BOM):encoding(UTF-8)", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";

のようにFile::BOM、encodingという順番に指定すると、文字列がある長さで切れます。
以下のプログラムはBOMつきのUTF-8において、「xxx yyyy1」から「xxx yyyy100」までの文字列を「 / 」区切りで出力しようとするものです。
#!/usr/bin/perl

# bomTest.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::BOM;
use feature 'say';

my $file = '/home/cf/Desktop/foo.txt';

open my $fh, ">:via(File::BOM):encoding(UTF-8)", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";

say $fh 'xxx yyyy1 / xxx yyyy2 / xxx yyyy3 / xxx yyyy4 / xxx yyyy5 / xxx yyyy6 / xxx yyyy7 / xxx yyyy8 / xxx yyyy9 / xxx yyyy10 / ' .
'xxx yyyy11 / xxx yyyy12 / xxx yyyy13 / xxx yyyy14 / xxx yyyy15 / xxx yyyy16 / xxx yyyy17 / xxx yyyy18 / xxx yyyy19 / xxx yyyy20 / ' .
（中略）
'xxx yyyy61 / xxx yyyy62 / xxx yyyy63 / xxx yyyy64 / xxx yyyy65 / xxx yyyy66 / xxx yyyy67 / xxx yyyy68 / xxx yyyy69 / xxx yyyy70 / ' .
'xxx yyyy71 / xxx yyyy72 / xxx yyyy73 / xxx yyyy74 / xxx yyyy75 / xxx yyyy76 / xxx yyyy77 / xxx yyyy78 / xxx yyyy79 / xxx yyyy80 / ' .
'xxx yyyy81 / xxx yyyy82 / xxx yyyy83 / xxx yyyy84 / xxx yyyy85 / xxx yyyy86 / xxx yyyy87 / xxx yyyy88 / xxx yyyy89 / xxx yyyy90 / ' .
'xxx yyyy91 / xxx yyyy92 / xxx yyyy93 / xxx yyyy94 / xxx yyyy95 / xxx yyyy96 / xxx yyyy97 / xxx yyyy98 / xxx yyyy99 / xxx yyyy100';

close $fh;

出力ファイルfoo.txtは、先頭にはBOM（0xEF BB BF）が正しく入るのですが、以下のようになります。

xxx yyyy1 / xxx yyyy2 / xxx yyyy3 / xxx yyyy4 / xxx yyyy5 / xxx yyyy6 / xxx yyyy7 / xxx yyyy8 / xxx yyyy9 / xxx yyyy10 / xxx yyyy11 / xxx yyyy12 / xxx yyyy13 / xxx yyyy14 / xxx yyyy15 / xxx yyyy16 / xxx yyyy17 / xxx yyyy18 / xxx yyyy19 / xxx yyyy20 / （中略） xxx yyyy61 / xxx yyyy62 / xxx yyyy63 / xxx yyyy64 / xxx yyyy65 / xxx yyyy66 / xxx yyyy67 / xxx yyyy68 / xxx yyyy69 / xxx yyyy70 / xxx yyyy71 / xxx yyyy72 / xxx yyyy73 / xxx yyyy74 / xxx yyyy75 / xxx yyyy76 / xxx yyyy77 / xxx yyyy78 / xxx yyyy79 / xxx yy

「xxx yyyy80」の途中で切れてしまいます。
これを
open my $fh, ">:encoding(UTF-8):via(File::BOM)", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";

のように、encoding、File::BOMの順に指定すると、きちんと「xxx yyyy100」まで完走します。
これは、どういう現象でしょうか。
PerlまたはFile::BOMモジュールのバグでしょうか。
あるいは合理的な仕様でしょうか。

英語版に重複質問して解決しました。:viaは常に最後だそうです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78534335/perl-the-order-of-filebom-module-and-encoding-and-output-defect/78535768#78535768

なぜかコメントに変換されてしまいましたが、これは根源的な回答です。
英語版に重複質問して解決しました。:viaは常に最後だそうです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78534335/perl-the-order-of-filebom-module-and-encoding-and-output-defect/78535768#78535768
:via(File::BOM)はopen関数の第2引数の末尾につけなければならず、それはきちんとドキュメントに明文化されているそうです。
質問をクローズしたいので自己解決したいのですが、なぜコメントになってしまったんでしょうかね。
これは大丈夫か？
